something strange is happening with the WAV sound recording
I want to make my own analogue for SSTV and I ran into a problem: when I start recording fast-changing beeps (which are 5 milliseconds long), very strange extra sounds appear
For creating beeps i used wave, math and struct library (solve to creating beeps)
So, when I started this code, I received this file with VERY strange sounds: (click to hear)
import math
import wave
import struct

audio = []
sample_rate = 44100.0

def append_sinewave(freq=440.0, duration_milliseconds=500): # i removed volume from example
    global audio
    num_samples = duration_milliseconds * (sample_rate / 1000.0)
    for x in range(int(num_samples)):
        #audio.append(volume * math.sin(2 * math.pi * freq * ( x / sample_rate )))
        audio.append(math.sin(2 * math.pi * freq * ( x / sample_rate )))
    return

def save_wav(file_name):
    wav_file=wave.open(file_name,"w")
    nchannels = 1
    sampwidth = 2
    nframes = len(audio)
    comptype = "NONE"
    compname = "not compressed"
    wav_file.setparams((nchannels, sampwidth, sample_rate, nframes, comptype, compname))
    for sample in audio:
        wav_file.writeframes(struct.pack('h', int( sample * 32767.0 )))
    wav_file.close()
    return

for i in range(1000): # creating sound
    append_sinewave(freq=400+5*i, duration_milliseconds=5)

save_wav("output.wav")

Also, when I increasing duration of beeps (see code below) this strange sounds disappeared (click to hear)
for i in range(20): # more duration fixes the problem
    append_sinewave(freq=400+250*i, duration_milliseconds=250)

save_wav("output.wav")

How to fix it?

I think in the first one your duration is not long enough to contain the entire beep. So, you end up with a bunch of pops in rapid succession that create the extra sound. In other words, the beep does not end at the zero point, but the next beep starts at the zero point so "pop, pop, pop, pop" every few milliseconds, and it's so fast that combined it sounds like distortion.

If you want the wave to be super clean, you'll likely have to figure out where each frequency crosses the zero point, and cut it there before going on to the next frequency, where you will have to do the same thing, again.

In addition to what OysterShucker said, you're not including any silence between the beeps, so you just have a continuous sine wave that is increasing in frequency.  You can make a simple modification to include a rest  between each beep, although my example here will have half as many beeps: beep_duration=100 rest_duration=50 for i in range(1000): # creating sound append_sinewave(freq=(400+5*i)*(i%2==0), duration_milliseconds=(beep_duration if i%2==0 else rest_duration))

I asked chatGPT questions that would fix the problem that I allege you have. Maybe this will help you. https://chatgpt.com/share/6723adc1-4ce0-800e-ac75-b55aa9a2ccee You'll have to play with it. I went quick and dirty on the prompts so, the answer it gave is a bit of a conglomeration.

For solve my problem, I made the beginning of the wave from the previous frequency, and and because of this, the very claps that spoiled the sound disappeared. Solution in the code:
# we need to edit only append_sinewave function
audio = []
sample_rate = 44100.0
last_phase = 0  # a variable to save the phase between beeps

def append_sinewave(freq=440.0, duration_milliseconds=500):
    global audio, last_phase
    num_samples = int(duration_milliseconds * (sample_rate / 1000.0))
    
    # adding a signal while continuing the phase
    for x in range(num_samples):
        phase = last_phase + 2 * math.pi * freq * (x / sample_rate)
        sample = math.sin(phase)
        audio.append(sample)
    
    # save the phase so that the next frequency continues the wave
    last_phase += 2 * math.pi * freq * (num_samples / sample_rate)
    last_phase %= 2 * math.pi  # normalizing
    return

Thanks to OysterShucker for idea

Yeah, that works, too. I'm currently writing an audio app and had an issue similar to yours. Similar in regards to me not considering zero-crossings and getting unwanted pops. In my experience, chatGPT is pretty good at providing formulas for manipulating WAV arrays. If you have more issues, I would suggest asking chatGPT first. You'll probably get a working solution on the first try. I've even told GPT, to give me better answers, and it does. You just have to define "better" ( faster, optimized, etc).
